# Code completion Hippo CMS in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, code-completion, hippocms

I've been trying to get this auto-completion for hippo cms tags to work but I just can't get it to work in IntelliJ IDE 2017! I've followed the guide from;
https://www.onehippo.org/library/development/develop-with-intellij.html

But it dosen't really help at all.. So I was wondering if somebod else had a solution to this?

The problem can be seen as in the screenshot thats its marked red, and intelliJ finds it unresolved even tho its compiling fine.

- Its a maven project

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Wlo.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add dependency under the project-structure ../bootstrap/webfiles/pom.xml ;

dependency; https://www.onehippo.org/library/development/develop-with-intellij.html

2. now you have to add Web application support;

right-clicking on the projectstructe ../bootstrap/webfiles    ---->  Add Framework Support  --->  choose Web Application AND remember to Unmark the "Create web.xml"

3. After this is done, try to check if the code-completion is working.

   - If it's not then you have to Reimport Maven this is done by pressing the refresh button.. which you can find in the Maven Projects menu tab.

What I as well found was that the Hippo team already had a problem to get code-completion to work in IntelliJ;
https://issues.onehippo.com/browse/ARCHE-512

Comment: for me is still broken. It can't even recognize classes that are in the same project.